# How do I save my dashboard on tableau public?

Tags: tableau-api

I have tableau public on which I have created visualization. Now I want to save my work but everytime I try to save it on tableau public it gives me an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an account in https://public.tableau.com/s/
make sure you're signed in Tableau public

[image]

[image]

[image]